# How to add an UIView as a subview to Storyboard's view without any delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, addsubview

I'm not for sure if my title responds what I want to ask but let me explain;

I'm using storyboard, I have created *"HomeViewController"* and set it as custom class. 
Also, I want to create a view with programmatically and add this view to *"HomeViewController"* 's view.

[image]

These TabBar, GreenView and Logout Button are necessary. Because I added them via interface builder to see how quickly they appear on the screen and whenever I build and run my app, these components are load very quickly. They are not blinking or appear after a sec. They are stable!

Here is a simple code;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIView *dummyView = [UIView new];
[dummyView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[dummyView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view addSubview:dummyView];}
```

When I run my code, the dummyView with yellow color appears on my view, yes, but with a delay of few seconds. It is really annoying!

Could you give me any idea please? When I use .xib I don't have any issues like this.

- What should I do to show my view while my application starts without
  any delay?
- Is viewDidLoad method good enough for this? How about loadView method?
- What is the reason I had this issue on storyboard?

**Updated**

I'm going to upload a .gif:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: add it in viewDidAppear!

Comment: I did before, and when I see your answer I did it again. But result is the same. View is still appear later on! @TejaNandamuri

Comment: I created a sample project like yours but I can't see any blinking or delay, do you see this behaviour on the simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: It's just your myth man or this is special case because there is no difference between adding view to storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: I did try both and they are the same! @lorenzoliveto

Comment: Yes I know, it is silly thing. Like I said I never had this on .xib etc. But on storyboard, I don't know? @KetanParmar

Comment: It's just illusion. There is no difference. I have also tried just.

Comment: No believe me there is a difference. The view with created by interface builder load quicker than then the view with programmatically. It is a big deal @KetanParmar

Comment: give a try with put your code in dispatch_async () may help ...

Comment: run your code in real device not simulator

Comment: @PKT thanks but as I wrote it before its the same on my real device :/ I couls try dispatch but I don't think it is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, its really silly thing. 
On my project there wasn't any SplashScreen. So it was immediately launch my main and it looks like views appears after some delay.

I have added SplashScreen and everything is as it should be!